# Elliptic Curve Digital Signature algorithm fails

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa

I would like to monitor step by step running of ECDSA.

Parameters I am working on:

- The elliptic curve satisfies the equation: $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$.
- I picked up the base point $G$ as: $(0, 1)$
- Finally, the modulo $p$ is $977$

My private key is $19$. Thereby, my public key is equal to $19\times G$ and its coordinates are $(396, 650)$. Suppose that my hash is equal to $14$.

Then, I picked up a random key. It would be $17$. So, random point would be $17\times G$ and it is equal to $(699, 739)$.

My signature is pair of $r$ and $s$, where $r$ is $x$ coordinate of my random point, and $s$ can be calculated as:
$$\begin{align}
r &= 699\\
s &= ((\text{random key})^{-1} \bmod p)\cdot(\text{hash} + r \cdot (\text{my private key}))\\
&= (17^{-1}\bmod 977)\cdot(14 + 699\cdot19)\bmod 977\\
&= (115\cdot13295)\bmod977\\
&= 1528925\bmod977\\
&= 897
\end{align}$$
So, my signature is $(699, 897)$.

Let's verify the signature
$$\begin{align}
w &= s^{-1}\bmod p\\
&= 897^{-1}\bmod 977\\
&= 403\\
u_1 &= \text{hash} \cdot w \bmod p\\
&= 14 \cdot 403 \bmod 977\\
&= 5642 \bmod 977\\
&= 757\\
u_2 &= r \cdot w \bmod p\\
&= 7699 \cdot 403 \bmod 977\\
&= 281697 \bmod977\\
&= 321
\end{align}$$

Now, I calculate the checkpoint
$$\begin{align}
\text{checkpoint}&=u_1\times G + u_2\times(\text{public key})\\
&= 757\times(0, 1) + 321\times(396, 650)\\
&=(707, 48)
\end{align}$$

Finally, I need to compare the $x$ coordinate of checkpoint and $r$ value of signature. But $x$ coordinate of checkpoint is $707$ whereas $r$ value was $699$. They are not same. This means that signature is invalid. But they should be equal! Anyone can help where I am wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In the question, $p$ designates the modulus of the base field $\mathbb Z_p$, as confirmed by the fact that for  $p=977$ and the curve $y^2\equiv x^3+x+1\pmod p$, it holds that $19\times(0,1)=(396,650)$ and $17\times(0,1)=(699,739)$.

Problem is, in other steps, the question reduces $r$, $s$ and related quantities modulo that same $p$, rather than modulo the order $n$ of the group generated by $G$. That's more than enough to cause the observed failure.

As an aside, the ECDSA specification requires that $n$ is prime . In the question, the curve and $G$ is such that $n=987=3\cdot7\cdot47$ is composite. One consequence is that nearly half the choices of $\text{random key}$ are invalid, and I'm uncertain about if it otherwise makes some signature unverifiable. We do not care about the possible security implications since $p$ is so small as to make the whole thing insecure anyway.

I suggest $p=1033$, which will give a prime $n=1061$.

Comment: slight correction: while it's common that $n < p$, there are standard curves for which $n$ is greater than $p$, `secp160r1` is one curves like this

Comment: @Hubert Kario: Thanks, didn't knew that fact some recommended curves use $n>p$. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I understand the problem and fix it.

I worked on F977. This means that point addition calculations will be realized on mod 977. Let's express this modulo as p (p = 977).

I added based point (0, 1) recurrently and this reveals that there are 986 point this finite field.

P: (0, 1)

2P: (733, 121)

3P: (72, 611)

...

985P: (733, 856)

986P: (0, 976)

987P fails because it requires to divide something to 0.

That's why **order of the group** is equal to 987 because of the existing 986 points and additional infinite point. Let's say this as order (order = 987)

I would use mod p which is 977 to calculate public key and random point. This values remain same as in my previous post.

public key: (396, 650)

random point: (699, 739)

But I would use mod order which is 987 instead of mod p when calculation r and s.

r = x coordinate of random point mod order

s = [(hash + r * private key) * ((random key)^-1 mod order)] mod order

Herein, pair of r and s would be like that:

(r, s) = (699, 724)

Pair of r and s are our signature

Let's monitor the verification process...

w = s^-1 mod order

u1 and u2 calculations would be interesting because they contain both mod p and mod order.

u1 = (base point) x (hash * w mod order) mod p = (492, 698)

u2 = (public key) x (r * w mor order) mod p = (780, 58)

checkpoint = u1 + u2 mod p = (699, 739)

Finally, x coordinate of checkpoint and r would be compared. They are both 699. This means that our signature is valid.

**To sum up, my problem was based on discarding order of the group.**

Comment: Yes. However, you really want to pick $p$ so that the order $n$ is prime, if only so that most $r$ will do. See my answer.

Comment: not only selection of $p$ has impact on primality of $n$, selection of $a$ and $b$ does too (where $y^2=x^3+ax+b\text{ mod }p$), so if you want a particular prime, you can just keep changing $a$ and $b$ until you get an $n$ that's prime too. For example, with $p=977$, $a=432$ and $b=520$, $G=(3, 572)$ has order $n=991$